# PHP change write permissions

Tags: php, apache

Sorry if this is a repost, but I've been having a bit of difficulty writing files to my disk in PHP. I'm trying to upload a file using an HTML form, and then download that file to my computer using a PHP file, but I keep getting the error

`Warning: fopen(temp/127.0.0.1): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\VotingBox\processForm.php on line 30`

I've already tried to `chmod` the directory to give myself write privileges, and the directory was created under an administrator profile in Windows 7, so it should have file-writing capabilities, but I still get the same error. Here's my code for writing the files:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
if(is_dir("temp/".$ip) == false)
{
    mkdir("temp/".$ip, 0777);
}
chmod("temp/".$ip, 0777);
move_uploaded_file($candImgs[$i], "temp/".$ip);
$filename1 = "temp/".$ip; 
$fp1 = fopen($filename1, "r");
$contents1 = fread($fp1, filesize($filename1)); 
fclose($fp1); `
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'm using XAMPP to host my files, if that is of any help.

Comment: you might want to find out what user apache is running under.  The user might not have permission.

Comment: it's running under an admin profile, so it should have read/write permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that the problem was with my HTML form, and not with the php code. Here are the useful parts of my final code if anyone else has this problem:

```
<form name="FORM_NAME" enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post' action="ACTION">

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="170000" />
```

And finally my php code:

```
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileName']['tmp_name'], $target_path);  
    $fp      = fopen($target_path, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($target_path));
    fclose($fp);
    $encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
```